# Flattering objects + arrays + objects into one object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I will go straight to the point, so here is what I have:

```
    const someObj = {
    one: [
        {
            id: 123,
            text: "lalala"
        },
        {
            id: 456,
            text: "lalala2"
        },
        {
            id: 789,
            text: "lalala3"
        }
    ],
    two: [
        {
            id: 111,
            text: "text random"
        },
        {
            id: 222,
            text: "text random2"
        },
        {
            id: 333,
            text: "text random3"
        }
    ]
};
```

and this is what I need to have:

```
    const someOtherObj = {
    111: {
        id: 111,
            text: "text random"
    },
    222: {
        id: 222,
        text: "text random2"
    },
    333: {
        id: 333,
        text: "text random3"
    },
    123: {
        id: 123,
        text: "lalala"
    },
    456: {
        id: 456,
        text: "lalala2"
    },
    789: {
        id: 789,
        text: "lalala3"
    }
};
```

I know this can be achieved without million loops, just I can't think of any smart solution. :/ So, maybe someone can help me to solve this puzzle? :)

Thanks :)

Comment: There are several hundred posts on Stack Overflow alone about how to flatten arrays and objects. Why don't you try something, then come to us with a specific question on where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6k__ZrIbVAhXGvI8KHSvMD2EQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q) function with `ES6`

1. first `reduce` created array with  all inner Object
2. Second `reduce` used to create object key with `id`

```js
const someObj = { one: [ { id: 123, text: "lalala" }, { id: 456, text: "lalala2" }, { id: 789, text: "lalala3" } ], two: [ { id: 111, text: "text random" }, { id: 222, text: "text random2" }, { id: 333, text: "text random3" } ] };

var res = Object.values(someObj).reduce((a,b)=> (b.forEach(val=> a.push(val)),a),[])

var f = res.reduce((a,b)=> (a[b.id] = b, a),{})
console.log(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use two loops, no more (using ES6 seeing that your example used it as well)

```
const newObj = {};
for(const key in someObj) {
  for(let i = 0; i < someObj[key].length; i++) {
    const obj = someObj[key][i];
    newObj[obj.id] = {
      id: obj.id,
      text: obj.text
    }
  }
}
```